# Creating window box for user input of attributes from layer and zoom to that layer based on attributes using ArcPy with ArcMap

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

I am new to intermediate in GIS but newish to Python. I received a task from work:
Create a window box (which in the end to be used as a toolbar button) which receives user input for
selecting attributes (section, township, range, meridian, scale) in order to quickly zoom to that area. The layer is a polygon. So really, "go there and there" (based on attributes) and zoom to "this scale". This needs to work in ArcMap 10.8.

So far I am using a Model Builder/Python hybrid but would like to transition to Python only. The "Script" part contains this:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('CURRENT')
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers") [0]
scl = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

df.zoomToSelectedFeatures()
df.scale = scl

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? You're more likely to get good answers if you show what you have attempted already.

Comment: You specifically mentioned Python, have a look at [Python Addins](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/python-addins/what-is-a-python-add-in.htm).

Comment: Thank you. So far I was only able to make a hybrid Model Builder + Python that gives me something somewhat ok. Why is my question "off-topic"?